# Unsubscribing from events - performance hit?

Tags: c#, event-handling

Consider the following code (from a performance report):

[image: Performance report]

This is part of a property notificiation listener component. The method `OnItemPropertyChanged` is a private instance-bound method with the `PropertyChangedEventHandler` signature. This method is called around 100.000 times and is causing significant delays in the application.

Are there performance considerations related to (un)subscribing events? Is there an explanation to why this would cause such a performance hit?

Comment: I think your problem lays in _This method is called around 100.000 times_ rather than the unsubscribe itself. Maybe you should consider a redesign

Comment: Why is this event being called 100,000 times?

Comment: all your items changed? if this is true you really have a problem; else call it where you really need it

Comment: There are 100k items in memory that each have a listener.

Comment: If each of those 100k items each need to invoke a `PropertyChanged` event, i think you should re-consider the design of your app

Comment: I agree with the redesign comments but am in no position to change it unfortunately. The issue has been resolved; see my answer for details.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With regards to the design flaw that many comments suggest: we have strongly opinioned users that will not sway from putting an object graph with 100k objects as a whole into the user interface; this is part of an ongoing improvement process and will hopefully be resolved in the future.

There was no significant difference between the `sharedHandler` and `Method` reference being passed to the unsubscription operator.

Using the [weak event manager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.weakeventmanager%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) classes removes the performance hit; with or without creating delegates like [Marc Gravell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24238897/unsubscribing-from-events-performance-hit/24239037#24239037) suggests. Perhaps this is related to this class creating its own event listener in a different way instead of using the one supplied in its argument. I have looked into the [source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#WindowsBase/src/Base/System/Windows/WeakEventManager.cs#63c23936e7130931) but could not find an explanation as to why this pattern does seem to work fast (since the `+=` and `-=` operators are still called).

Comment: I would expect that it's still taking the same amount of time, it's just happening off your main execution thread. The WeakEventManager pattern looks like it detaches the handlers when (or shortly after) objects are garbage collected. This means it will happen on a background thread and the users will not have to wait while it's happening.

Comment: We are manually invoking RemoveHandler though; this should immediately remove the event handler?

Answer (score 16):

The first thing to note is that:

```
notificationItem.PropertyChanged -= OnItemPropertyChanged;
```

actually **allocated** a new delegate for the purpose. It also means that the equivalence test can't short-circuit at *identity* equivalence - it has to perform method/target equivalence (i.e. a different delegate instance, but same target/method, hence considered equivalent for the purposes of delegate combination).

What I would try *first* would be using a single delegate instance, i.e.

```
void OnItemPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs args) {...}

private readonly PropertyChangedEventHandler sharedHandler;
public YourType() { // constructor
    sharedHandler = OnItemPropertyChanged;
}
```

Then when you subscribe, instead of:

```
notificationItem.PropertyChanged += OnItemPropertyChanged;
```

or

```
notificationItem.PropertyChanged -= OnItemPropertyChanged;
```

use instead:

```
notificationItem.PropertyChanged += sharedHandler;
```

or

```
notificationItem.PropertyChanged -= sharedHandler;
```

Worth a try, at least.

Comment: Why is the CLR/Compiler/... designed like that? Wouldn't it be possible to automatically refactor this situation so it always somehow uses ReferenceEquals internally? I mean the compiler (or jitter) could extract the targetMethod and directly compare it. Wouldn't it be possible to somehow implement that at a lower level? (CLR, Jit, or as syntactical sugar like var/foreach/enumerators)

Comment: @Felheart it can't use `ReferenceEquals` **because it isn't the same delegate instance**. `PropertyChanged -= OnItemPropertyChanged` is essentially `PropertyChanged -= new PropertyChangedEventHandler(this.OnItemPropertyChanged)`, where in reality the `this` and the `OnItemPropertyChanged` are provided separately. The plumbing passes around the `PropertyChangedEventHandler` instance, not the pair `this` / `OnItemPropertyChanged`

Answer (score 14):

Pay attention that `94.2%` is related to the *relative* execution time. So unsubscribing takes `94.2%` of total execution time of `Disable(..)` method. And considering that other code raw are `cast` and `null` check, it's normal.

The *real* problem, imo (even if anything in regard of performance is strictly related to concrete execution context) is that this method is called `100.000` times.