# Efficient alternative for (unsubscribe from) events

Tags: c#, performance, events

In my application, some value can change at any time. A lot of components need to do something when this value changes. The number of components changes during the usage of the application (depending on what the user opens). Currently this is implemented with events: when value changes, an event is raised, on which all interested components are subscribed.

Of course, to avoid memory leaks, these components unsubscribe on dispose.

When we stress-test our application with lots of components (a few million), one of the biggest bottle necks (>90% cpu time during high loads) are these subscriptions: `MyApp.ValueChanged -= TheValueChanged;` takes very long (multiple seconds).

I assume this is, because there are a lot of subscribers, and this unsubscribe needs to find the correct subscriber in the list of subscribers (worst case: a million time searching in a list of a million items).

Now, my question: What would be a good way to improve this?

I was thinking about weak event handlers, so unsubscribing isn't necessary, but there may be better solutions.

Comment: Make a static bool variable that you can test in the event and just return from event when variable is false.

Comment: Do all your subscribers unsibscribe simultaneously or these unsubscribe at different moments in your app life cicle?

Comment: They are unsubscribed when the component is closed, or not necessary anymore. In practice, one to many components are disposed when the user closes/finishes something in the application. When the user closes everything, almost all components are unsubscribed.

Comment: You could try to implement the `add` and `remove` methods of the event yourself in a way more streamlined to your usage pattern.

Comment: How many events and how many subscribers do you have? Are you sure all the unsubscribes are correct? It can be fairly easy to subscribe a temporary delegate that cannot be unsubscribed, and this might cause a very long list of subscribers after some time.

Comment: Maybe your event listener is the last reference to some very heavy object. When removed, the `GC` then collects the referenced data, causing a delay of a few seconds?

Comment: @l33t The GC only runs when allocating objects, not when releasing references. The GC cannot know if all references to an object are released before it has been run. Your comment would be correct if it used reference counting, but it does not. And the GC execution time typically scales with the amount of live objects, not dead objects.

Comment: @JonasH Yeah right... `GC` can run at ANY time. After releasing/nulling references it gets a chance to *collect* the unreferenced objects. If there are many objects to collect, the `GC` will block for a significant amount of time. My comment is indeed very accurate.

Comment: But yes, I'm assuming that the OP left out some details. E.g. the hickup was identified by a profiler where that particular line was highlighted. I then guess (from experience) that the OP incorrectly interpreted that piece of information. Guessing is needed when the question is lacking information :P

Comment: In the stress tests (which reflects real world environments we want to expand our application to), we're talking about a few million components subscribed to that event. 
The bottleneck was determined with CPU profiling: >90% of CPU time is spent in the unsubscribe.

A quick PoC with some kind of weak reference event manager (tweaked to our specific use case) looks very promising.

Comment: @l33t The problem with your logic is you're assuming that cleaning up dead objects is what's expensive, but that's not how the GC works.  When a collections happens all live objects are moved, and all dead objects get ignored.  It takes *no work* to clean up a dead object, it takes work to keep live objects alive (as well as work to find all of the objects that should be alive, which scales with the live objects, not the dead objects).  So removing the last reference to a large number of objects neither triggers a collection nor does it make the next collection shower, it makes it *faster*.

Comment: Valid points, all of you. Let me rephrase what I meant. If a profiler points at heavy CPU load on a **quick** operation like unsubscribing an event, my #1 advice is to look for "GC Wait". I.e. OP is likely running an app with 2,5+ GB RAM usage (yes, that's a critical threshold) causing the tiniest allocation to imply a `GC`. @Coder14, please tell us more about the app's characteristics. E.g. memory usage, object types (lists, dictionaries?)... Do you have some profiler data/screenshots to share?

Comment: @l33t They mentioned the profiler data.  The time is spent unsubscribing events, which makes sense, since unsubscribing millions of items from a multicasxt delegate *performs poorly*, since it's designed to scale for only a handful of delegates, not millions.  They didn't say that the time was spent in the GC, which makes sense, because this isn't a use case that would cause abnormal collection times.

Comment: Interesting discussion, guys. To give some more info: during the stress test we reach easily above 2.5 GB RAM (64 bit).

Comment: @Servy Why spend time trying to prove an invalid point? Unsubscribing from an event is *definitely* a use case that would cause abnormal collection times. In fact, I cannot think of a built-in pattern in .NET that would cause more allocations than this very operation. **Proof** [here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/multicastdelegate.cs,360).

Comment: @l33t Why spend time trying to prove an invalid point?  It's the *creation* of new objects that causes lots of GC pressure, not the *releasing* of them.  Yes, subscribing and unsubscribing from events with millions of items is *really* inefficient.  *That* is the problem, not the unrooting of objects that's the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**GC is the culprit. Period.**

First of all, the default implementation of strong event handlers is not optimized for many listeners. To get decent performance, consider implementing the event handler explicitly. Using a hash set we can improve on the default implementation which internally uses a flat list.

### The fix

For your event, implement `add` and `remove` using a `HashSet`. Note that this implementation is **not thread-safe**. You might want to add a locking mechanism if multiple threads will be using the event.

```cs
class Publisher : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private HashSet<PropertyChangedEventHandler> propertyChangedHandlers =
        new HashSet<PropertyChangedEventHandler>();

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged
    {
        add => propertyChangedHandlers.Add(value);
        remove => propertyChangedHandlers.Remove(value);
    }

    public void Signal()
    {
        var args = new PropertyChangedEventArgs(null);
        foreach (var handler in propertyChangedHandlers)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(null));
        }
    }

    public void RemoveSubscribers(IEnumerable<Listener> listeners)
    {
        foreach (var listener in listeners)
        {
            listener.Subscribe(this);
        }
    }
}
```

This will perform a lot better. But **why**? Sure, removing items from a hash set is a lot faster than traversing a flat list, but it's not *that* slow. The extreme CPU time actually comes from `GC`. When unsubscribing an event, the list of handlers will be re-allocated. The old list will then, quite soon, get collected by the Garbage Collector.

### Analysis

In your case, you have `1,000,000` event handlers. So each time you unsubscribe an event handler, a list of `N` items (where `N` is near 1000000) is unreferenced and a new list of `N-1` handlers is allocated. Do this 100 times, and the `GC` will have lots of data to memory to collect:

100 * 1000000 * 8 bytes = **~800 MB**

We can easily prove this using the [GC.TryStartNoGCRegion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.gc.trystartnogcregion?view=netcore-3.1) API. The sample below tries to unsubscribe 20 event handlers, but since this operation will indeed allocate more than the requested **128 MB**, it will fail:

> Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: Allocated
> memory exceeds specified memory for NoGCRegion mode    at
> System.GC.EndNoGCRegionWorker()

```cs
class Publisher : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}

class Listener
{
    public void Subscribe(Publisher publisher)
    {
        publisher.PropertyChanged += OnPropertyChanged;
    }

    public void Unsubscribe(Publisher publisher)
    {
        publisher.PropertyChanged -= OnPropertyChanged;
    }

    private static void OnPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"OnPropertyChanged called for {nameof(Listener)} {sender}");
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var publisher = new Publisher();

        var listeners = Enumerable.Range(0, 1000000)
            .Select(p => new Listener())
            .ToList();

        foreach (var listener in listeners)
        {
            listener.Subscribe(publisher);
        }

        var watch = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
        watch.Start();

        const int toRemove = 20;

        if (GC.TryStartNoGCRegion(128L * 1024L * 1024L, true))
        {
            try
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < toRemove; i++)
                {
                    listeners[i].Unsubscribe(publisher);
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                watch.Stop();
                var time = watch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
                Console.WriteLine($"Removing {toRemove} handlers: {time} ms");
                GC.EndNoGCRegion();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If we run a memory profiler, we can see that *removing* event handlers does indeed cause allocations and `GC`.

[image: Allocations when removing event handlers.]

See [MulticastDelegate.cs(360)](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/multicastdelegate.cs,360) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

I found this answer, which suggest another possible improvement: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24239037/1851717

However, some experimentation led me to the decision to go with my first thought: use a weak event manager, to skip unsubscribing altogether. I've written a custom weak event manager, as there are some extra optimizations I could do, making use of some application-specifc characteristics.

So in general, summarizing the comments, and solutions, when your event unsubscribing is a bottleneck, check these things:

- Is it really the bottleneck? Check if GC'ing could be the issue.
- Can a refactor avoid the event/unsubscribe?
- Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/24239037/1851717
- Consider using a weak event manager, to avoid unsubscribing

Comment: Weak events use roughly 10 times more RAM (1 kB per listener, last time I checked). You also lose the deterministic behavior; e.g. dangling event handlers (to be reclaimed by the system at some point).